# Computing the exterior derivative of a Riemannian metric

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds

Consider a Riemannian metric on a smooth manifold X expressed by local coordinates $(x_1, ..., x_n)$ on a connected open set $U \subseteq X$, 
$$g = \sum_{i,j=1}^{n} g_{i,j} dx_i \otimes dx_j$$
I am very confused by the $\otimes$ on the right hand side: I'm not clear on how the exterior derivative $d$ would distribute over such products. (Ie. can I use here the rule that $d(\alpha \wedge \beta) = d\alpha \wedge \beta + (-1)^k \alpha \wedge d\beta$?) How can I compute the exterior derivative of g?

Comment: There is no such thing as the exterior derivative of $g$, since $g$ is symmetric rather than antisymmetric.

Comment: @user10354138 that would explain my confusion... You might want to post this as an answer so that I can accept something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exterior derivative operator $d : \Omega^\bullet(X) \to \Omega^\bullet(X)$ is defined on the graded algebra
$$\Omega^\bullet(X) = \bigoplus_{k=0}^\infty \Omega^k(X) $$
of linear combinations of differential forms of all degrees. The elements of $\Omega^\bullet(X)$ are assignments of a linear combination of totally covariant, *totally alternating* tensors to each point of $X$. In this context, the identity that you mention can be established for all tensor fields $\alpha \in \Omega^k(X)$ and $\beta \in \Omega^\ell(X)$.

A Riemannian metric $g$ is by definition a 2-covector field that is *totally symmetric*, so the object $dg$ is not defined. You can, however, calculate its *covariant derivative* with respect to a vector field $X$: see [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2750912/332594) to another question.

Comment: Just one more question: what is the exterior derivative of the 1-form $dx_i$?

Comment: @gen It is $0$, since $d^2 = 0$.

Comment: Ah, of course, I see it now. I am just trying to compute the Lie derivative $L_v g$ of the above expression in my original question, that's why the slightly random question. But now I think I have all the bits I need! Thank you